# Css image path in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Within my cshtml view, i am having one div with

Id="top-navigation"

Css class defined as below in css

```
div#top-navigation 
{
background:url('/Content/Images/bg-top-nav.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x;
height:37px;
border:1px solid #7bcdeb;
border-bottom:1px solid #7ad5f5;
}
```

My objective is to give as below

```
background:url('mysite.com/Content/Images/bg-top-nav.jpg')
```

but problem is, i dont want to hardcode mysite.com domain name.

what could be the solution? whether i can access server variable within css ?

Comment: Why won't a root relative path like the first example work for you?

Comment: 'coz these views/htmls will get injected thru dynamic javascript to some-other-page-section-of-different-domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dot Less CSS

http://www.dotlesscss.org/

and try declaring

@domain:'dynamic_domain_name' in your .cshtml page and use it. Here its like CSS defined in page.

Comment: anyother alternative without thirdparty ?

Comment: Not its not third party. Its open source project &  free. Otherwise you need to create a one similar like this and try.